# bootstrap-table data reset when pagination toggle is changed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I'm facing an issue which reset my selected entry in a col when click or select a pagination change.

For example.
At first, I display ma data into the table and in a col there's a select box.
There's lots of page to display (1, 2, 3)
I change a content of the select box in the page #1, next I click on pagination toggle. And the content is reset (it doesn't keep my selection before).

```
data-maintain-selected="true"
```

I expected that is keep this one after pagination change, but not.
Is there a way to keep this data ?

Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Untitled</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function pagin() {
     $("#table").bootstrapTable("togglePagination");
   }
 </script>
<div id="page_body">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="fpbx-container">
          <div class="display full-border">
            <button onclick="pagin()">
              Pagination On/Off
            </button>

            <table id="table" data-show-toggle="True" data-maintain-selected="true" data-pagination="True" class="table table-striped"></table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>    

</body>

</html>
```

And Javascript on load.

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
columns: [{
    field: 'id',
    title: 'Item ID'
}, {
    field: 'name',
    title: 'Item Name'
}, {
    field: 'price',
    title: 'Item Price'
}],
data: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Item 1',
    price: '<select><option value="10">$10</option><option value="20">$20</option></select>'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Item 2',
    price: '<select><option value="10">$10</option><option value="20">$20</option></select>'
}]
});
```

JSFiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/fdanard/n0ky502r/3/

If somebody want to help me and avoid to delete and modify my thread. :)

Comment: Please post your code, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's done but no answer.

Comment: maintainSelected is related to keep checkbox selections, like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/hgLzx0c0/

Comment: Hi.
yes i known for checkbox it works.
That issue was how to maintain the selected data like for a checkbox. ;)
maintainSelected there's select, and it should works for any select box as well.
Otherwise, rename this one like: maintainChecked if maintainSelect is not used for select box. :D
I joke but this is the idea. 
maintainSelect should work for both.

But thanks for you reply.

Answer (score 0):

The data should strictly be the data for the table.  Any HTML objects or special formatting in data column can be setup using the formatter (data-formatter)

```
function formatForks(value, row, index) {

  var selectCode = '<select>';
  var forksAllowed = [0, 10, 20, 30];

  forksAllowed.forEach(function(ii) {
selectCode += '<option value="' + ii + '"'  + (value==ii?' selected ':'') +'>$' + ii + '</option>';
```

});

```
  selectCode += '</select>'
  return selectCode;
}
```

see this JSFiddle - [note the forksFormatter function](http://jsfiddle.net/jimkennelly/5ndep94v/)

Comment: Ok, but does this example keep the selected data when you click on pagination toggle? No! :(

Comment: Yes - YOU need to add the update function. The example was to show the proper way to add a select box.  You could also use the editable extension.